# Curling HTTPS does not resolve

Tags: php, curl, https

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
// Edit: prior variable $postFields should be $postfields;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

print_r($result);
$array_json = json_decode($result, true);
```

I tried to do a curl to a https site, it say the dns cannot be resolve. But that site I can access it by browser

```
https://example.com [example]
```

Comment: Does this link help you? http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did test on my own local installment

```
$ch = curl_init();

$curl_url = 'https://example.com';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
// Edit: prior variable $postFields should be $postfields;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
  echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

print_r($result);
```

It works correct and print result. I suppose you problem is in this string

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
```

You could past wrong path or load wrong certificate. I comment this line in my example.